# Logarithms in MARIE

Tags: operators, computer-science, calculation, marie

How would I write a MARIE Assembly code that calculates logarithms. Input A and STORE A Input B and Store B. Enter in 2 in A and 16 in B would print a result and show an output 4. Log base 2 of 16 = 4.

Comment: Are you able to do it in C or other language? If you don't know how then you're looking for an algorithm, and you don't have to think in assembly to come up with an algorithm.  Then, take that to assembly.

Comment: yes I did. I already have C program, but I need it MARIE ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE.

Comment: Ok, good.  So, how you write a MARIE assembly code is to first, (1) develop an algorithm, because it is necessary to know what you want the program to do (and you already have that), and then (2) translate that algorithm into assembly language.  (Translating an existing algorithm into assembly is much easier than developing an algorithm in an assembly language you don't know.)  Suggest to ask question about translation then, best to show your work, what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: thanks I had it figured out, it was a capitalization error inside marie